# Issue with JAVAFX fxml - Text Area Auto Shrinking

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

We are using **JavaFX** to create the text area and populate the text area values dynamically. The display of text area is working some times and some times the text area is getting shrinks and values are not displayed. However If I right click in the text area and select all then copy and paste it in notepad I could see the text.

So i'm assuming something wrong with the Text Area itself.

test.fxml

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <TextArea id="notes" fx:id="notes" editable="false" prefHeight="152.0" prefWidth="675.0" styleClass="notes" text="%welcome.note" wrapText="true" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
```

[image: Working]

[image: Not working]

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: You could consider anchoring the text Area. Related info can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/inspector-panel.htm)